# How to load images from remote PHP-MySQL blob with Picasso?

Tags: php, android, android-listview, blob, picasso

I have a MySQL db, where there are the blobs of the images I want to load to a Listview.

I am trying to utilize Picasso. But the problem is-
How do I do a POST request, sending the parameters by ($_POST in PHP)-converting it to an url, and finally the library loads it into an imageview? Which is the best option?

My current implementation for fetching the images is as follows:

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ----------------------------
    ----------------------------



    if (!"N".equalsIgnoreCase(listOfPosts.get(position).getHasImage()) ) {
        if(mMemoryCache.get(postId)== null )
            new GetPrimaryImages(position, holder).execute(image);
        else
             holder.ivPrimaryImage.setImageBitmap(mMemoryCache.get(postId));
    }else {
        holder.ivPrimaryImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.search);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

Where GetPrimaryImages class looks like this:

```
  public class GetPrimaryImages extends AsyncTask<Image, Void, Bitmap> {


    int mPosition;
    Holder mHolder;
    public GetPrimaryImages(int position, Holder holder){
        mPosition = position;
        mHolder = holder;
    }


    ImageView imageView = null;
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Image... images) {
    this.imageView=images[0].getImg();



        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postid",(String)(this.imageView.getTag()) ));

        JSONObject json;

        if(mHolder.position == mPosition)
             json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(CommonResources.getURL("get_primary_image"),
                    "POST", params);

        else {
            json = null;
            cancel(true);
        }


        if(json == null){
            //latch.countDown();
            return null;
        }
        Log.d("Fetching Image",imageView.getTag()+ json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 0) {
               image =  json.getString("primaryimage");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return getImage(image);

    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (mHolder.position == mPosition) {
            mMemoryCache.put((String) imageView.getTag(), result);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    }






}
```

Comment: What is the reason why you storing Images in the database. Do you see an advantage in that?

Comment: I have a lot of images to be stored.
Plus I am new to this and thought this is the only way to store images!

Comment: No its not the only way. You put the images in directories and put the link for each image as text in the db. Othewise you will have a very large database, and also if you have 1000's of requests going through the db it will slow it down given the fact of the image size. There are some disadvantages for using directories, such as deleting an image accidentally or moving them around, where storing images in db is safer, but they are ways round safeguarding images in folders anyway, such as user permissions and monitoring sync

Answer (score 0):

Tty this

Picasso.with(context).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.no_image).into(imageview);

Comment: How do I send this:
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postid",(String)(this.imageView.getTag()) ));

Comment: You get image URL from server?

Comment: No, I get the image directly.
I make a post request to my server, which a parameter(postid here), and I get back the String, which I convert to Bitmap.